# trouble adding roles through reaction role for my discord bot

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, node-modules

**so im trying to set up a reaction roles command and i get error:**

```
*DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\mreap\Desktop\orbit project, etc\box militia\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\mreap\Desktop\orbit project, etc\box militia\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async GuildMemberRoleManager.add (C:\Users\mreap\Desktop\orbit project, etc\box militia\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberRoleManager.js:124:7) {
  method: 'put',
  path: '/guilds/1015814032088891462/members/1173097778843496620/roles/1015880336665743382',  
  code: 50013,
  httpStatus: 403,
  requestData: { json: undefined, files: [] }
}*
```

my code looks like this if you have any insight please help me:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS"] });

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
});

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  if (message.content === '!reaction_role') {
    const reactionMessage = await message.channel.send('React to this message to get the role!');
    reactionMessage.react('✅');
  }
});

client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
  if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
    const guild = reaction.message.guild;
    const member = guild.members.cache.get(user.id);
    let role = guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'test'); // Replace YOUR_ROLE_NAME with the name of the role you want to assign
    member.roles.add(role.id);
  }
});

client.login('token');
```

`
ive read on other pages nothing seems to work ive rewritten all the code ive tried youtube reaction roles isnt wanting to work for me, the bot has permissions it is administrator and the bot role is at the top above all others

Comment: Enable (Privileged Gateway Intents ) from the discord developer portal and import Intents.FLAGS.(the intent you need)

Comment: https://prnt.sc/aavoX_zeJRzD

Comment: thats already been done on the discord developer and i thought i had declared the intents already above or is there another way to do so? this is how i thought i was declaring the intents if its wrong how do i fix?

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS"] }); @Matze._

Comment: yeah sorry, overlooked that. 
error code: 50013 means that you don't have permission to perform that action.

Are you sure, that you have set all the Permissions the bot needs, it is at the top of the role list and has the Administrator role?

Comment: Could you log `console.log(guild.me.roles.highest.position, member.roles.highest.position)` before `member.roles.add(role.id)` for us?